# Unable to create object context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting the `Unable to create object context` error when using Entity framework in ASP.NET MVC.

#### Background

Every time I `POST` to the controller I'm not getting a response back. I tried going directly to the method of the controller `/Data/GetAll`, and receive this error:

#### Error

> The specified named connection is
>   either not found in the configuration,
>   not intended to be used with the
>   EntityClient provider, or not valid.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   `System.ArgumentException:` The
>   specified named connection is either
>   not found in the configuration, not
>   intended to be used with the
>   EntityClient provider, or not valid.

#### Code Snippet that throws exception:

```
public class TrackItContextCreator {
    public ObjectContext Create() {
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext("name=TrackItDBEntities");

        context.DefaultContainerName = "TrackItDBEntities";

        return context;
    }
}
```

#### Web.config

```
<add name="TrackItDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*
/EntityFramework.TrackItDBModel.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.TrackItDBModel.ssdl|res:
//*/EntityFramework.TrackItDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
 connection string=&quot;Data Source=host;User ID=myuseracc;Password=******;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: My first guess seems to have been wrong.  Next question: Is the model in a separate assembly?

Comment: yes it is...... damn character requirements lol

Answer (score 7):

From the comments, I think I know what the problem is.

If the model is in a separate assembly, you basically have to make sure that the connection string is specified in the `app.config`/`web.config` of *every* assembly that uses the model.  I'm guessing that you only have it in the model project.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113361/ado-net-entity-connection-string-for-multiple-projects) for another example, and [this thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f5904b4d-b2f8-421e-90de-339f93959533/).  Both similar issues involving models being in separate projects/assemblies.  I'm 99% sure that this is related to your issue.

Comment: @Downvoter: I edited to clarify, but if you down-voted because you think it's the wrong answer, I suggest you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158853/entity-framework-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-connectionstring

Comment: It shouldn't affect it, I have another project that uses &quot; and it works. That was auto generated by the Entity Framework when I created it.

Comment: hmmm you were right I was missing it in the web.config of the main assembly, but none of the other ones had app.config/web.config files... the issue still isn't fixed. Any ideas?

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer. You must either put a correctly-named Entity Framework connection string in the config file of the *executing* assembly, or supply a connection string in code.

Comment: @Matt: If you're still getting the exact same issue then there's probably something incorrect in the config.  What happens if you try to get the connection string manually through `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrackItDBEntities"]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you develop web app with class libarary you should add databases' connectionStrings to both of Web.Config and App.Config.